# java concurrency in practice 14.6

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

This code snippet from java concurrency in practice, I really don't understand.

```
@ThreadSafe
public class BoundedBuffer<V> extends BaseBoundedBuffer<V> {
    // CONDITION PREDICATE: not-full (!isFull())
    // CONDITION PREDICATE: not-empty (!isEmpty())

    public BoundedBuffer(int size) { super(size); }

    // BLOCKS-UNTIL: not-full
    public  synchronized  void put(V v) throws InterruptedException {
        while (isFull())
            wait();
        doPut(v);
        notifyAll();
    }

    // BLOCKS-UNTIL: not-empty
    public  dsynchronize  V take() throws InterruptedException {
        while (isEmpty())
            wait();
        V v = doTake();
        notifyAll();
        return v;
    }
}
```

the put and take methods are synchronized. If some thread is waiting in put method, no one can ever enter take or put method, So, in most of the cases, if a thread start to wait, it will wait for ever.

Am I miss-understand something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `synchronized` but the `wait()` method released the lock if it waits -- that's how it works.  The thread then blocks until it is notified.  Once notified, it reacquires the lock and continues.  To quote the `Object.wait()` javadocs:

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the java.lang.Object.notify() method or the java.lang.Object.notifyAll() method for this object. In other words, this method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the call wait(0).
>
> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.

I'd recommend doing some more reading about [Java concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/), specifically this section on [guarded blocked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html).

It is more typical to specify specifically which object you are waiting and notifying.  The `wait()` call really should be `this.wait()` and `this.notifyAll()` which makes it easier to be able to figure out which lock is being affected.

Comment: Sorry, for this newbie question.

Comment: Np dude.  Just make sure you read the docs about threading.  You will be confused and it will be harder road otherwise.